# Unable to rewrite a CSS to XPATH with multiple classes and skipping elements

Tags: jquery, python, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to rewrite a css to XPATH.  The css is shortened to:

```
div:nth-child(1) > .lay-selection-button span.bet-button-price
```

I am trying to write an xpath equivalent.

```
//div[1]/button[starts-with(@class=’lay-selection-button span.bet-button-price’)]//span[@class=’bet-button-price’]
```

Any idea why it is not working.

It is from this [site](https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football) or an image is [here](https://ibb.co/k5bYLm)

The full css is:

```
#main-wrapper > div > div.scrollable-panes-height-taker > div > div.page-content.nested-scrollable-pane-parent > div > div > div > div.content-page-center-column.coupon-center-column > div > div:nth-child(1) > main > ng-include:nth-child(3) > section.coupon-card.coupon-card-first > div.card-content > bf-coupon-table > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.coupon-runners > div:nth-child(1) > button.bf-bet-button.lay-button.lay-selection-button > div > span.bet-button-price
```

Shortened to:

```
 div:nth-child(1) > button.bf-bet-button.lay-button.lay-selection-button > div > span.bet-button-price
```

And finally what I have at the top:

```
div:nth-child(1) > .lay-selection-button span.bet-button-price
```

Comment: How many button will you get when using following css: button.lay-selection-button  span.bet-button-price?

Comment: @TonyBui 3 columns.  I believe I've shortened that CSS as much as you can for one column.  I'm unsure how to make that an xpath

Comment: your xpath seems not correct: could you try this: //div[1]/button[starts-with(@class=’lay-selection-button’)]//span[@class=’bet-button-price’]

Comment: @TonyBui I'm using Chrome inspect and it's not showing up.  HMM

Comment: Which output do you want? The first value in table only (which is currently `1.01`)?

Comment: @Andersson A list of values for the column.  CSS div:nth-child(1) > .lay-selection-button span.bet-button-price works but trying to do an xpath equivalent

Comment: All values from the first column (currently `1.01, 14, 48...`), right?

Comment: @Andersson I believe so.  That's the pink 1st column you are referring to?  This one: https://ibb.co/m7njRR

Comment: how about using contains function: //div[1]/button[contains(@class,’lay-selection-button’)]/‌​/span[@class=’bet-bu‌​tton-price’]

Comment: I thought about the first blue on:) You need pink only? Or both?

Comment: @Andersson Well at the moment I want just the pink 1st column.  But if you can provide xpaths individually for both that is even better as I'll go through other columns after this.

Comment: @TonyBui Hmm still not working in my Chrome inspect for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the `price` values from the first blue column with below code:

```
for cell in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[1]/button[@price][1]'):
    print(cell.get_attribute('price'))
```

For first pink column:

```
for cell in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[1]/button[@price][2]'):
    print(cell.get_attribute('price'))
```

If you want to get `size` value instead of `price` - just replace `cell.get_attribute('price')` with `cell.get_attribute('size')`

You can use `//div[2]` to get values from second blue/pink column, `//div[3]` to get values for third one

Answer (score 1):

Here is xpath, not to write additional code:

```
//tr//*[contains(@class,'coupon-runner')][1]/button[2]//span[contains(@class,'bet-button-price')]
```

Comment: Cheers.  Also a useful way to write it

Comment: yep, define structure of document and logically follow it) you can also wrap this into method and path parameters to `tr, button and coupon-runner position`, so basically this xpath will work to select any cell in table